# How to calculate the the variation of Cl wrt the angle of defection of the elevator?

Tags: wing, horizontal-stabilizer, tail, empennage

I've checked the lift requirements of the aircraft and selected an optimal airfoil and designed a wing with dimensions of MAC 47cm and semi-span of 163.2 cm and a airfoil S1223. The horizontal stabilizer has a MAC of 17.5cm and semi span of 50cm with NACA 0012.

How can I calculate the change in Cl of the elevator with respect to the angle of deflection of the elevator?